# Openbox/PCManFM/LXDE, how can I assign the middle mouse button as Alt+F11 fullscreen?

Tags: mouse, openbox, lxde, pcmanfm

I'm using Openbox/PCManFM/LXDE in a Linux distro based on Ubuntu 16.04.1 (LXLE) and I want the middle button of my mouse to do exactly the same as Alt+F11 does (ToggleFullScreen) in every application. I tried a few things in rc.xml file but I was not able to do it.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to do this using Keystroke Gesture Recognition, I set a single click action for the group of applications I wanted and it works perfectly.